# How to refresh an HTML page using JS, PHP or HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've spent two days trying to make a login/logout panel in PHP. I'm using one PHP file which checks if you are already logged in by a session variable and echoes the appropriate "panel".

The problem I have is that after logging in and out, I have to refresh the page so the other panel actually appears. I've found that in PHP is done through `header()` but I'm having a problem implementing that because I always get the headers have been sent thing. Anyway after many hours I decided to go with javascript, so I made a basic `redirect(url)` function that takes a URL and opens that page and I'm passing `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` to that so I go back to the same page, basically refreshing. But now I was thinking, If someone disables JS I'm going to have a problem with that.

Any alternatives I'm not aware of?
Cheers

Comment: Aren't you already refreshing the page when somebody logs in or out, or are you using ajax for that?

Comment: You could look into Meta Redirect's (HTML) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: By the way, the php `header` function is the way to go if you need to redirect and should not give you any trouble if you have your logic on top and the output to the browser at the end.

Comment: @jeroen This is all done for an assessment and I really don't have time looking into AJAX right now.

Comment: @jeroen I really tried about the header thing, believe me. But I have tried to have different php files for different things and doing that is kinda hard for my experience

Comment: @christian.thomas that doesn't seem like a solution for my problem exactly because I'm not trying to update the whole page all the time. Just log in and out.

Comment: Try removing spaces, newlines before an opening \'< ?php\' tag or after a closing \'?>\' tag. This will solve your header already sent issue.

Comment: @Santeron If you are not using ajax, just posting the login or logout form causes the page to refresh so if you output your panel after the login / logout action handler, your problem is already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript Solution:

```
var newURL = "http://THE-URL.com";
document.location.href = newURL;
```

or

```
location.reload(true);
```

HTML solution:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://THE-URL.com">
```

PHP solution:

```
// taken from http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=228678.0
function redirect($loc){
    echo "<script>window.location.href='".$loc."'</script>";
}
function GoHere(){
    redirect('http://THE-URL.com');
}
```

or

```
header( "refresh: 2; url='http://THE-URL.com'" );
```

User Solution:

```
Press F5
```

Comment: So I think that's about it really :P

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces, newlines, or other garbage before an opening `<?php` tag or after a closing `?>` tag to solve ***headers already sent*** issue

Answer (score 0):

Try making your logout script it's own page. Make the logout link point there and then unset the session variable. You can get the page referrer and send them back to it.

Comment: "it" meaning the page that they came from to logout.

Answer (score -1):

To solve the problem of headers already sent, just add:

```
ob_start();
```

at the start of your code.

Comment: It's generally better to fix the underlying structural problem.

Comment: add it where? On the <?php ?> before everything?